# Window 7 64 bit: using shift + arrow down and ctrl + shift + arrow left move cursor but select nothing

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

Hi all I've installed window 7 64 bit.
I have a very strange problem using all application installed (e.g. notepad++, eclipse, notepad, ecc).
a) pressing shift + arrow down
The cursor moves down of 1 line but the line above is not selected
b) pressing ctrl + shift + arrow left
The cursors moves to the next word but nothing on the left is select.
Example if I press ctrl + shift + arror left with cursor on the left of ThisIsAnExample
the cursor moves on left of I but the word This is not selected.

I've performed several search in several forums nd I've see that is there some applications that might cause that problem, just like clownfish, lenovo monitor driver or some mouse driver or strictly keys enabled, but in my sytem is not there any of that conditions.

Does someone has any suggestion to help me to solve my problem?
Thanks in advance for your time

Comment: does your shift button work? in any case how is this question programming-related?

Answer (score 0):

at least I've found the root of problem.
I've updated logmein to latest version (4.1.0.3430) and the problem is solved.